# how to update hierarchical query with leaf node =1

Tags: sql, oracle

how to upadate hierarchical query with leaf node =1

and update them

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER SET CLASS='SHIP-TO' (when the leaf=1)
```

something like this ,but this wont work

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER SET CLASS='SHIP-TO' 
   WHERE connect_by_isleaf=1 and
   start with cust_id=12660
   CONNECT BY PRIOR cust_id = cust_cust_id;
```

Comment: what is the structure of your CUSTOMER table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the structure of your table and input data. But, maybe this will work:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER SET CLASS='SHIP-TO' 
WHERE cust_id in 
(SELECT cust_id 
FROM CUSTOMER
     CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF=1 
     START WITH id = 12660 CONNECT BY PRIOR cust_id = cust_cust_id)
```